# Is the VoicePackage ID guaranteed to be stable?

Tags: android, here-api

Using HERE Android SDK Premium, our use-case is as follows:

- We want to display the list of available voice packages to the user
- When user chooses one, we want to save the ID of the selected VoicePackage to persistent storage.
- On app start, we want to use this ID to obtain an instance of `VoiceSkin` (either locally or download it if it is not available locally)
- Set this voice skin on `NavigationManager`

**Question**: is it safe to persist the ID of a VoicePackage in this way? Is a particular ID guaranteed to always refer to the same language?

Answer (score 1):

Officially the VoiceIDs are not guaranteed to be stable. Workflow should be to regularly update the catalog, and use these IDs you retrieve thought the catalog.

But in practice the risk that VoiceIDs change are very, very low - at least I am not aware of any change in the last years (new skins came in with new IDs, naming scheme changed from prerecorded to TTS skins, and so of course, but existing ones didn't change as far as I can remember). If your effort of updating the catalog is high or not possible, you could consider taking that risk in my personal opinion.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by the "workflow" above? Are you suggesting that ideally we should not store the voice package ID; instead store something like MARC code, BCP47 code etc; then regularly refresh the catalog and search through it for a package that corresponds to this stored code?

Comment: In most usecases, users get a list of languages to select from and they can choose they language for navigation. There it makes absolutely sense to use the catalog. If you know already the language you want upfront, you have to check effort and benefit. As said, I never saw the IDs really changing. In the end, downloading the catalog, iterating over the list, searching for your language code and then retrieve the language based by the returned ID are just few lines more code. Both will work, first one is shorter, latter one more robust.